# How should I change my query in order to apply a function on each record of the Array in BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am a bit new to using BigQuery. I currently implement the function to Arrays using WITH statements, in which I first create a query that selects the array column, unnest it, and apply the function to the unnested array table. Finally, I'll join this processed table with the original table.

However, I encountered a problem when using WITH and LIMIT queries. I expect the joined result to always exist since the processed table is the same as the original. However, after I join the tables, I found the result to be unstable, sometimes the results exist but more often it doesn't.

**Background Context:**

The table which I want to query is time partitioned by day and originally contains JSON data, so I want to parse it into proper BigQuery schema and data types, also hashing the private information. The data in the final form will consist of various BigQuery data types from primitives to complexes like ARRAY or RECORD.

Here is the snippet of my query to illustrate my case:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION ConvertToArrayOfString(input STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  return JSON.parse(input);
""";

WITH
  timestamp_ranges AS (
  SELECT
    TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), DAY) AS start_timestamp,
    TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), DAY) AS end_timestamp,
  ),
  filtered_data0 AS(
    SELECT
      *,
      _PARTITIONTIME AS partition_time
    FROM `project-id.dataset.booking_table`, timestamp_ranges
    WHERE
      _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN start_timestamp
      AND end_timestamp
    LIMIT 100
  ),
  transformed_data0 AS (
    SELECT
      COALESCE(SAFE_CAST(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, '$.id') AS INT64), id) AS id,
      STRUCT(
          TO_HEX(SHA256(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, '$.contact.name'))) AS name, 
          ConvertToArrayOfString(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.contact.phone')) AS phone,
          TO_HEX(SHA256(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, '$.contact.email'))) AS email
      ) AS contact,
    FROM filtered_data0
  ),
  hashed_details AS (
    SELECT
      id,
      ARRAY_AGG(TO_HEX(SHA256(p))) AS phone
    FROM transformed_data0, UNNEST(contact.phone) p
    GROUP BY id
  ),
 transformed_data1 AS (
   SELECT 
     LSQ.* EXCEPT (contact),
     STRUCT(
       LSQ.contact.name,
       COALESCE(RSQ.phone, LSQ.contact.phone) AS phone,
       LSQ.contact.email
     ) AS contact
   FROM transformed_data0 LSQ
     JOIN hashed_details RSQ
     ON LSQ.id = RSQ.id
)
SELECT
  LSQ.id as l_id,
  RSQ.id as r_id
FROM transformed_data0 LSQ
FULL JOIN hashed_details RSQ
USING(id)
```

The query above is mainly composed of the following queries:

1. `filtered_data0`: filters out table by partition and rows limit
2. `transformed_data0`: select columns from filtered data, parse JSON strings to BigQuery schema
3. `hashed_details`: hash private information that still exists in `transformed_data0` which exist in ARRAY form
4. `transformed_data1`: joins `hashed_details` with `transformed_data0`
5. `main query`: check full join between `hashed_details` and `transformed_data0`

So here, I expect `transformed_data1` results to exist. However, most of the times I keep getting an empty result. I tried to debug this problem with my main query, and discovered that the data (identified by id) that exist in `transformed_data0` and `hashed_details` **are different**.

Why and how does this problem occur? Is this due to some query order processing?

If you see the query, `hashed_details` is actually using `transformed_data0` as the source so I'm expecting the data in `hashed_details` to be the same as `transformed_data0`. Note that this data difference problem won't occur if I moved the `LIMIT` query from `filtered_data0` to the `main query` below. But this will degrade the performance as the query processing time will be significantly longer.

Please let me know if you have any answers or a better solution to solve my problem (which is originally applying a function on each record of the array). Thank you.

#### Solution

1. Making the Query Deterministic (thanks to Raymond Nijland)
   Add `ORDER BY` when using `LIMIT` to make the query deterministic
2. Applying Function to Arrays
   Use UNNEST in ARRAY subquery. This transforms all my query and eliminates the need for joining tables.

Comment: I would not advice using the SQL tag in combination with Google-bigquery.. Google-bigquery deviates on some basic fronts alot from the ISO/ANSI SQL standard the ISO/ANSI SQL comma join (`FROM t1, t2`) for example which should be a CROSS JOIN or INNER JOIN is in Google bigquery a UNION..

Comment: Also i would not advice to use LIMIT without using ORDER BY to get the first 100 matching records as the result can be non deterministic (random).. i believe Google bigquery also not give the same deterministic (fixed) order without using ORDER BY on the primary or unique key.. That is how SQL normally works..

Comment: Seems you're right about the `ORDER BY` @RaymondNijland, now my query works! I had a hunch that my problem has something similar with how SQL normally works that's why I initially added the SQL tag in my question hehe. Thanks!

Comment: *" I had a hunch that it has something to do with how SQL normally works that's why I initially added the SQL tag in my question"* In fact ANSI/ISO SQL standards does not even allow limiting resultsets into subqueries without using a `ORDER BY`, SQL 2006+ i believe defined `FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY` for limiting resultsets which needs to be used with `ORDER BY` in a subquery before it's valid SQL.